# Inverted normals only in unity not blender

Tags: normals, unity

Whenever I load my model into unity it shows up like this:

[image]

The tube that should be on the right side is inverted.

In Blender, it is all blue when I have *Face Orientation* on. I also have backface culling on and it still looks fine! When I invert the normals for it, it just becomes very dark in unity and inverted in Blender.

https://pasteall.org/blend/5cfc27281a98401aba3a49d5d9dc4523

[image]

Comment: Please share your file so that we can see what's going on. https://pasteall.org/blend/ and don't forget to add the link to your question.

Comment: I don't know Unity, but your model is actually facing backwards in Blender. Press 1 on the numpad and it shows the back, whereas CTRL-1 shows the front. Also the 3D cursor isn't on the world origin which is affecting the position of one of your tubes.

Comment: How would that have any effect to my normals?

Comment: It wouldn't but you're asking why one of the tubes is inverted in your question and face normals wouldn't have anything to do with the position of your tube.

Comment: So, this isn't going to fix my problem?

Comment: It was only a suggestion. As I said, I don't know Unity so someone else here who also uses it might be able to help.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think you just forgot to export the tube.

Comment: No, it is just inverted.

Comment: @SomeRandomCoder have you tried to re-export and import it? I tried your file and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that you may just have missed the left tube when you imported/exported it.

I exported your file to FBX format and this is what I got in Unity when I imported the FBX file :

[image]

As you can see, the tube is there.

I would suggest you to check in your Unity scene and search for the mesh and the object named `NurbsPath.001`. If you don't have it, then you just forgot to include it in the import/export somehow :

[image]

One thing I can assure you is that the normals of your tube **are not inverted**. At least, they are not in the file that you linked to us.

If the problem is persistant, you can just re-export the objects from Blender and import it again.

Comment: I have the tube but when I look at the tube from the side I see the outside of the tube in the inside. I'll edit it to show the image.

Comment: Have you tried exporting and importing again? The file you gave us doesn't give that result.

Comment: What do you mean? As in the fbx?

Comment: Yes export again from blender as an fbx and import that fbx in Unity.

Comment: I have multiple times

Comment: Can you share the fbx you exported?

Comment: How am I supposed to?

Comment: You can use pasteall.org or any other file sharing website and then share the link here.